# iPhone openAL effects

Tags: iphone, openal

I'm trying to build an app that has some functionality similar to tweakybeat, specifically the sound manipulation. I'm using openAL, however I can't figure out how to apply effects like pitch decay, pitch start or waveform.
I was wondering if I should generate the sound using a mathematical function and filling the buffer with a specific length in mind, or am I just thinking this all wrong and should I be doing this some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can generate the sound samples algorithmically (and just feed them to an Audio Queue or RemoteIO Audio Unit API), you will have far more control than using the limited OpenAL API.

Comment: And would I be able to change the sound in real time, ie, after it started, change how it sounds?

Comment: @Oscar Olim : Depends on the audio buffer sizes and latency, and whether or how fast you can update/change the samples you feed these buffers.